# Using spring with objects injected via JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, managed-bean

I have a large existing application with a bunch of managed-beans that are injected via **JSF's ioc**.

I want to start **autowiring** things into these beans. Currently i cannot do so because these beans are not created via spring.

What is the easiest way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make spring get control over JSF injection by using a special EL Resolver (in faces-config.xml):

```
<el-resolver>
   org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
</el-resolver>
```

If you are using JSF 2.0, it's advisable that you try CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection)